# GTK+3 in C lang: how to set MAXIMUM length of ProgressBar?

Tags: gtk

I'm totally in trouble. Wanna set maximum width of progressbar, but the only thing I found is min- properties, that can be set through CSS. What else can I do?

Comment: Shouldn't you set the maximum width of the container where the GtkProgressBar is put into?

Comment: Tried to put it into the box, but I can't set max width of box too

Comment: Putted into another one layout, I can change size of it, but it just cutted my progressbar

Comment: Please add a minimal and reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably have found out through research, the CSS "max-width" property is not a property currently handled via the GTK CSS provider.  In testing out various scenarios with a progress bar, it seems that the constricting factor is the width allowances of the various GTK containers.  And, the only container that appeared to allow for adjusting the width of a progress bar was within a "GtkBox" container.  Following is a minimal program I composed to test out various widths for a progress bar (FYI, this is GTK3).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *prog = NULL;
    GtkWidget *win  = NULL;
    GtkWidget *box  = NULL;
    
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    
    win  = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    box  = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 2);
    prog = gtk_progress_bar_new();
    
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (win), "Progress Max");
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (win), 20);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(win), 400, 120);
    g_signal_connect (win, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
    
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (win), box);
    
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(prog, 200, 20);  /* Vary the length to test the effect */
    
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), prog, FALSE, TRUE, 40);
    
    gtk_widget_show_all (win);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Make note of the size values in the "gtk_widget_set_size_request" function to determine your progress bar width, and note the boolean values for the "fill" and "padding" parameters in the "gtk_box_pack_start" function.  I believe that if you experiment with those statements that you should be able to control the desired width of your progress bar.

Regards.